# Decoding encrypted footer

Tags: php, decode, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode this PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364009/how-to-decode-this-php-code)

Can i ask for the help of someone to decrytpt this encoded footer.

Basically I would like to remove the links, mostly the link for Ford For Sale as that is blatent blackgat SEO trick for this theme.

```
if (!function_exists("T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29")) {
    function T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E) {
        $TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E = base64_decode($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E);
        $T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29 = 0;
        $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571 = 0;
        $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 = 0;
        $TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[1]) << 8) + ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[2]);
        $T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA = 3;
        $T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012 = 0;
        $TDFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF = 16;
        $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196 = "";
        $TDD7536794B63BF90ECCFD37F9B147D7F = strlen($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E);
        $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85 = __FILE__;
        $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85 = file_get_contents($TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85);
        $TA5F3C6A11B03839D46AF9FB43C97C188 = 0;
        preg_match(base64_decode("LyhwcmludHxzcHJpbnR8ZWNobykv"), $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85, $TA5F3C6A11B03839D46AF9FB43C97C188);
        for (; $T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA < $TDD7536794B63BF90ECCFD37F9B147D7F;) {
            if (count($TA5F3C6A11B03839D46AF9FB43C97C188)) exit;
            if ($TDFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF == 0) {
                $TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) << 8);
                $TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 += ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]);
                $TDFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF = 16;
            }
            if ($TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 & 0x8000) {
                $T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) << 4);
                $T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29 += (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA]) >> 4);
                if ($T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29) {
                    $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) & 0x0F) + 3;
                    for ($T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 = 0; $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 < $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571; $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257++) $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196[$T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012 + $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257] = $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196[$T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012 - $T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29 + $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257];
                    $T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012 += $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571;
                } else {
                    $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571 = (ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) << 8);
                    $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571 += ord($TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++]) + 16;
                    for ($T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 = 0; $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257 < $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571; $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196[$T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012 + $T0D61F8370CAD1D412F80B84D143E1257++] = $TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA]);
                    $T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++;
                    $T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012 += $T9D5ED678FE57BCCA610140957AFAB571;
                }
            } else $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196[$T800618943025315F869E4E1F09471012++] = $TF186217753C37B9B9F958D906208506E[$T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA++];
            $TF623E75AF30E62BBD73D6DF5B50BB7B5 <<= 1;
            $TDFCF28D0734569A6A693BC8194DE62BF--;
            if ($T3A3EA00CFC35332CEDF6E5E9A32E94DA == $TDD7536794B63BF90ECCFD37F9B147D7F) {
                $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85 = implode("", $TC1D9F50F86825A1A2302EC2449C17196);
                $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85 = "?".">".$TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85."<"."?";
                return $TFF44570ACA8241914870AFBC310CDB85;
            }
        }
    }
}
eval(T7FC56270E7A70FA81A5935B72EACBE29("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"));
```

And would like to remove any adsense stuff, and check for any malicious code.
When i look into the source from browser it comes up as this:-

> ```
>    </div>
> ```

```
    <div class="footAdsense"></div>

    <div class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2011 <a href="http://pettswoodfc.net/new/"  title="pettswoodfc.net">pettswoodfc.net</a>. All Rights Reserved | Designed by <a href="http://themes.rock-kitty.net/" title="FREE Wordpress Themes" target="_blank">FREE Wordpress Themes</a> and <a href="http://www.jennings-ford.co.uk/usedsales/summary/fordfocus.aspx" title="Ford Focus for Sale" target="_blank">Ford Focus for Sale</a></div>

</div>
```

pettswoodfc bit is ok, but the rest of it i dont trust.

Now when I delete the contents of this encrypted data, it messes up the fonts on the page too,

Comment: @user702718 why not remove that whole bit from the footer and just fix the footer?

Comment: coz it messes up all the fonts for some reason

Comment: also noticed this in there i think this is the fonts bit


</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pettswoodfc.net/new/wp-content/themes/FootBall/js/functions.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pettswoodfc.net/new/wp-content/themes/FootBall/js/HandelGothicEF.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pettswoodfc.net/new/wp-content/themes/FootBall/js/football.js"></script>

  <div id="wpadminbar"> 
   <div class="quicklinks"> 
    <ul>

Comment: @user702718 there must be some font styles embedded as well. If this is part of the footer, my recommendation is to look at your static HTML, save a copy of it. Then remove this code and replace the missing parts by looking at the static HTML

Comment: when i delete the code it also removes the sidebar on the right :(

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just delete the whole bit and replace it with the unencoded footer code? If it then messes up the fonts, use the inspector or Firebug to compare the font styling on body and your h1,h2 etc and manually write the code to fix it.

I suspect that would be quicker than trying to decode it in any meaningful way.

In addition, you can probably find the same theme somewhere else that doesn't have this obfuscation – these are sometimes pirated themes that you are supposed to buy from the original author.

Comment: i tried that and now it messes up all the page, i need to know whats in it so i can post it plain.

Comment: ive googled for the same theme and cant find anything similar, it has to be one that looks like this just want to make sure of whats in it and why its being encryped/hidden?